# Simplify this Combination Expression

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Simplify the expression, where $m$ and $n$ are both positive integers:
$$
\dfrac{n\cdot C^{n+1}_{m+1}}{C^n_m}
$$
in fraction in terms of $m$ and $n$. The answer I got is $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{m+1}$ but the actual answer is $\dfrac{n(m+1)}{n+1}$. Not really sure how to get there.

Here's my working out:
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{n\cdot C^{n+1}_{m+1}}{C^n_m} &= \dfrac{n\cdot {\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(m+1)!(n-m)!}}}{\dfrac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}} \\
&= n\cdot {\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(m+1)!(n-m)!}}\cdot \dfrac{m!(n-m)!}{n!} \\
&= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{m+1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you show your computation, so that we dedect where you were mistaken?

Comment: Could you please introduce $C^n_m$ to me? Thanks!

Comment: @AnneBauval My Question has been updated, thank you!

Comment: @Matija $C^n_m=\dfrac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$

Comment: Here is your mistake. $C^n_m=\binom mn=\dfrac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $C_n^k$ denotes $\binom nk$, not $\binom kn$ as one would intuitively expect. Therefore the expression equals
$$n\cdot\frac{\binom{m+1}{n+1}}{\binom mn}=n\cdot\frac{(m+1)/(n+1)\cdot\binom mn}{\binom mn}=\frac{n(m+1)}{n+1}$$

Comment: Except that this "upside-down" is the true definition, which cannot be changed at will.

Comment: @AnneBauval Everyone agrees on what $\binom nk$ means, but not everyone agrees on what $C_k^n$ means. Unless OP produces actual printed proof of where the definition comes from you cannot say that.

Comment: It is not a matter of agreement, it is so. There is a huge amount of printed sources supporting the definition you call "upside down" and I know none for the other one. So it is the contrary: unless you produce a reliable source for your personal definition of $C^n_k$, your answer does a disservice to the reader.

Comment: @AnneBauval (-1) Knuth's Concrete Mathematics doesn't even use that notation at all. $C_k^n$ is a totally unknown notation to me. Which sources do you have?

Comment: *All* sources who use it (mainly old french manuals) + ISO/CEI 80000-2:2009 + https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_binomial +  the OP's source, according to what he reports from it

Comment: @AnneBauval edited.

Comment: Correct know. But I guess the OP already understood all that from my last comment to his post 7 hours ago.

Comment: Appreciate your help, I get it now! I realized that $C_m^n$ isn't a very common notation, but it happens to be the one I'm using in this problem. I'll keep the definition in mind.

Comment: @HetianFu will you upvote and accept my answer?